# Error when starting pure-ftpd

Tags: pureftpd

I installed pure-ftpd in freenas-jail. OS Freenas 11. Installed from ports
Now, when I try to start the server, I get an error:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/pure-ftpd: WARNING: run_rc_command: cannot run /usr/local/sbin/pure-config.pl
```

In /var/log/messages the same error.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the server again. It works now